# Multiple table left join

Tags: sql, node.js, mariadb

I'm trying to figure out a SQL query to pull data from multiple tables at once. Ive got a table with a list of companies. I have two other tables containing communications from each company. Currently, I'm looping through each company row and then performing a query for each communication table.
I've tried a query like:

```
SELECT c.*, 
       count(e.id) AS ecount, 
       count(p.id) AS pcount 
FROM companies c 
LEFT JOIN emails e 
  ON c.id = e.company 
LEFT JOIN push p 
  ON c.id = p.company
```

But results for this query only contain one company and no counts. How can I accomplish this query?

Comment: You are only selecting one company, so why is it surprising that only one is returned?

Comment: Apologies. I was copying the wrong line when I put the selection on the end. Query has been updated

Comment: This is difficult to debug without some sample data. Can you post some data? and table ddl's?

Comment: As it should.  It can only get 1 company info at a time unless you join to company twice, once for each key in either emails or push.  We really need to see a sample data set for these 3 tables and the expected results to help.  But form what I can see you'd need to join to company again based on the 2nd foreign key in either emails or push or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.*, 
       (SELECT COUNT(e.id) FROM emails e WHERE e.company = c.id) as ecount,
       (SELECT COUNT(p.id) FROM push p   WHERE p.company = c.id) as pcount 
FROM companies c
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably intend:

```
SELECT c.*, 
       count(distinct e.id) AS ecount, 
       count(distinct p.id) AS pcount 
FROM companies c LEFT JOIN
     emails e 
     ON c.id = e.company LEFT JOIN
     push p
     ON c.id = p.company
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Assuming that `companies.id` is unique or a primary key, then this is a valid way to express the logic.

Comment: mariadb has the same free spirit regarding fields on `GROUP BY` as MySql?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . Yes, I believe so.  But grouping by a unique/primary key is not a "free spirit" type of thing.  It is supported by standard SQL.

Comment: But that select a random values for the fields not in the `GROUP BY`, doesn't? I find that non deterministic behaviour careless.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza . . . It works fine for unique/primary keys.  It is called a "functional dependency" and allowed by the standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.*, 
       ( SELECT count(e.id) FROM emails WHERE e.company = c.id ) AS ecount, 
       ...
    FROM companies c
```